# How can I delete a duplicate user via the command line in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, user-accounts

I accidentally force-created a user with the shortname "admin" after my Mac OS X machines already *had* users with the shortname "admin". What possible remedies are available to me in order to delete all traces of that second, spurious "admin" user?

(Ideally, this would be a command-line op because it needs to be repeated across the multitude of machines that now have an extra "admin".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dscl` is the command line utility to maintain OSX's user/group databases.  To explore what's there, `sudo dscl .` to get its command line, then `list /Users`.  To see the definition for a given user, use `read /Users/admin`.  As you might expect, removing it is `delete /Users/admin`.  (There's also a `help` command.)

For scripting, you can do these from the command line:

```
 $ sudo dscl . -read /Users/admin
```

That is, just add a `-` before the command name.

I'm pretty sure DirectoryService names must be unique, so I assume that your existing `admin` is `admin` and the bogus one must be `admin␣` or something silly like that.  Alternately, you might have one defined in `/etc/passwd` and one in DirectoryServices; the former will only be used during system boot, before `/usr/sbin/DirectoryService` is running.

Comment: I'm aware of dscl and have examined the users -- they are identical with the exception of GeneratedUID.

Comment: Looks like you can include that GeneratedUUID to select the specific record.  `dscl . -delete /Users/admin GeneratedUUID mumble`.